# Using Old Version of Node JS

Tags: node.js

Hi I have a Windows OS and I currently have the most up to date version of Node.JS running (which includes npm). I would really like build and compile 0.1.91 which can be found here http://nodejs.org/dist/. I'm extremely new to this and any all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think version v0.6.0 was the first build to officially support Windows... you probably can't get 0.1.91 to work in Windows (without cygwin).

Comment: thank you. I installed cygwin. Do you know how I would go about doing my initial task now that I have cygwin?

Comment: I have no idea... I'm a lowly intern. I do as am told.

Comment: @user1733207: I highly doubt that you'll actually be able to build .1 under Cygwin for the reasons in my answer below.  You're much better off simply **updating your code** that uses the 0.1 APIs to the modern APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Node first supported native Windows builds in the .5 dev branch.  To make it happen, they had to rewrite many internals from scratch – the platform compatibility layer now exists as [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv).

Before that, you had to build Node under Cygwin.  I remember building .4 in Windows with Cygwin, and it was a complete pain.  The GitHub wiki has since pulled down all Cygwin-related information since it's no longer relevant.  (If you *really* want to see how Cygwin builds were done, I suppose you could clone the wiki's [repo](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/_access) and go digging around.  The information isn't available online anymore.)

Support for building on Windows with Cygwin wasn't added until [0.1.98](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.8.11-release/ChangeLog#L2522), and support was dropped with .6.  So, the specific version you're trying to build won't work.

---

At any rate, it's a very bad idea to run very old software, especially something like Node 0.1, which was still very early in its development.  It's nearly guaranteed to be full of security holes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems like regardless of my inexperience/ difficulty of the task the deed must be done so I will follow your instructions and try to figure it out. RTFM I suppose.

Comment: @user1733207: In fact, the task is **impossible**.  According to the [changelog, Cygwin support wasn't added until 0.1.98](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.8.11-release/ChangeLog#L2522).  0.1.91 simply won't build/run on Windows/Cygwin.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but you should *not* be using node.js v. 0.1.98 for *anything*. Like really, nothing. If it's running and needs to be upgraded, upgrade it to a new version. If it's down and needs to be brought back up, bring it up in a new version. Anything built with node.js 0.1.98 was built as a toy with the expectation that it would be upgraded at some point.